# Add widget with editable properties through code

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I've created a custom widget plugin that is a container( it overloads the qframe). In this container i would like to add children through the code. I've succeeded in doing this. However the children aren't editable or clickable in the designer. I know for children to be editable through the designer, they should be added as code to the XML, but i don't know how to do this.

Would anybody know if it's at all possible to do this?

The code I have, with arrowedFrame as my custom widget plugin class:

```
arrowedFrame::arrowedFrame(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) : (parent, f)
{
    QLabel* testLabel = new QLabel(this);
}
```

this adds a new Label, as member (sorry i can't yet post pictures, but imagine a box with a label in it). But as i said this label isn't at all editable through the designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to this is by taking [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtdesigner-containerextension-example.html) guide. And adding some things in the initialize function:

```
void PlotContainerPlugin::initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface *formEditor)
{
    if (initialized)
        return;

    QExtensionManager *manager = formEditor->extensionManager();

    myFormEditor = formEditor;

    Q_ASSERT(manager != 0);
    manager->registerExtensions(factory, Q_TYPEID(QDesignerContainerExtension));

    initialized = true;
}
```

The first part just gets a manager:

```
QExtensionManager *manager = formEditor->extensionManager();
```

And then we use this manager to,

```
manager->registerExtensions(factory, Q_TYPEID(QDesignerContainerExtension));
```

register the plugin(a plotter I my case) with the designer.

Hope this helps:)